# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

He estado realizando un proyecto simple de aplicación con Spring MVC y Gradle. Sin embargo, el programa me sigue lanzado una excepción

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770

Probalmente es algo sencillo ya que es mi primer proyecto de Springboot creado desde cero sin seguir tutoriales o guias, tengo la sospecha que el problema inicia desde la configuración del archivo `build.gradle`

Les paso mi código para que me ayuden porque no he podido solucionar hasta el momento:

Controlador

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/areas")
public class AreasController {

    @Autowired
    AreasService areasService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Areas> getAll(){
        return areasService.getAreas();
    }

}
```

Service

```
public class AreasService {

    @Autowired
    private AreasRepository areasRepository;

    @Transactional
    public List<Areas> getAreas(){
        return areasRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface AreasRepository extends JpaRepository<Areas, Integer> {
}
```

Modelo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "areas")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Areas {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private Integer codigo;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "facultades_codigo", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
    private Facultades facultadesCodigo;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_coordinador", referencedColumnName = "identificacion")
    private Empleados idCoordinador;
}
```

Este es mi build.gradle

```
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id("org.hibernate.orm") version "6.2.4.Final"
}

group = 'com.BackendHybrid'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'

    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Información en Logs

````
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.BackendHybrid.BackendHybrid.BackendHybridApplication.main(BackendHybridApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.BackendHybrid.BackendHybrid.model.Areas
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.4.Final.jar:6.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.4.Final.jar:6.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.4.Final.jar:6.2.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0```
````

Comment: Afirmas hacerlo "sin apoyo de springboot", sin embargo tienes todas las dependencias de spring-boot metidas en el gradle. En qué quedamos, usas spring-boot o no? Porque si usas spring-boot, *necesitas* usar la configuración de spring-boot, no hay otra. SB no hace magia (casi, pero no), necesitas indicarle cómo cargar las configuraciones, servicios, todo... si no quieres usar spring-boot, no uses dependencias de SB, usa spring *"puro"*, con sus configuraciones correspondientes en xml o como quieras hacerlo, pero seguirás teniendo que configurar todo, y no solo el build.gradle...

Comment: Te recomiendo que si quieres usar spring "puro" (incluso si quieres usar SB en realidad) te mires un buen curso, porque son frameworks enormemente extensos y con infinidad de configuraciones y opciones. Si vas a usar SB, tus clases necesitan estar anotadas como `@RestController` y `@Service`, no solo anotar los `@Autowired`, estos le indican que quieres que inyecte la dependencia pero para ello tiene que tener un `@Service` de una clase que sirva para inyectar ahí! (O @Component, @Controller, @Repository... cualquiera de las anotaciones de componente sirven para el inyector de dependencias).

Comment: Hola Benito Disculpa la redacción, me refiero a que es un proyecto que estoy intentando hacer sin guias o tutoriales. Realmente el framework que eligo trabajar es Springboot.

Answer (score 0):

podrían ser varias cosas, pero dado que usas una versión relativamente reciente de Java, para el caso de Java 17+ las dependencias de las anotaciones de la capa de persistencia cambian.

Esto significa reemplazar todos los paquetes que inicien con

```
javax.*
```

por

```
jakarta.*
```

por ejemplo

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

se convierte en

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
```

### Por qué?

Las nuevas versiones de Java y Spring Boot han adoptado Jakarta EE al ser opensource a partir de JDK17 y/o Spring Boot v3. Esto aplica para aplicaciones hechas con [Quarkus](https://es.quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm), [Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6) y [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/blog/jakarta-ee-is-becoming-mainstream-get-ready-for-spring-boot-3-and-vaadin-24).